# Copying a list in Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a list that looks like this ( notice the list is of the pattern A, B, C etc..)

```
1.  [Insert question 1]
A.  [Insert response A]
B.  [Insert response B]
C.  [Insert response C]
D.  [Insert response D]

2.  [Insert question 2]
A.  [Insert response A]
B.  [Insert response B]
C.  [Insert response C]
D.  [Insert response D]
```

When I copy and paste it I want it to look exactly the same. However this does not happen. What I get instead is ( the A,B,C, pattern continues on with the rest of the alphabet)

```
1.  [Insert question 1]
A.  [Insert response A]
B.  [Insert response B]
C.  [Insert response C]
D.  [Insert response D]

2.  [Insert question 2]
A.  [Insert response A]
B.  [Insert response B]
C.  [Insert response C]
D.  [Insert response D]

3.  [Insert question 1]
E.  [Insert response A]
F.  [Insert response B]
G.  [Insert response C]
H.  [Insert response D]


4.  [Insert question 2]
I.  [Insert response A]
J.  [Insert response B]
K.  [Insert response C]
```

How do I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: The issue is the list is continuing from the previous series.  You must break that connection.  Right click on the next list and click on restart numbering.

Comment: I right-clicked and didn't see that option.

Comment: What version of Word are you referring to?

Comment: How about `Set Numbering Value`?